# Link to previous day in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I have a university-managed wiki with the basic templated from MediaWiki, but I have been adding more copying them from the Wikipedia templates. 
 We use it as a lab book so there is a page per day, e.g. `2018/02/02`.

I want to write a link to the *previous* day, i.e. yesterday, `2018/02/01`.

I tried:

`{{CURRENTYEAR}}/{{CURRENTMONTH}}/{{#expr:{{CURRENTDAY}}-1}}` ,

but this returns `2018/02/1`.

- How do I make the day have the `0` before the single digit? As in I want `2018/02/01` and not  `2018/02/1`.
- My method would only work for days within the same month. Is there a wikipedia template for *yesterday*? How would I write it for the generic date? With a bunch of `If` statements to check if the month has changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [#time parser function](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions##time) to do some date calculations (anything that's supported by the [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) PHP function), for example:

```
[[{{#time:Y/m/d|now - 1 day}}]]
```

Or for the day before a particular day:

```
[[{{#time:Y/m/d|1 April 2017 - 1 day}}]]
```

Comment: What about for a generic day? Not ‘now’.

Comment: Do you know how to get to the previous month in general? Like if I am in January 2018 and I want to link to December 2017?

Comment: @SuperCiocia yes, you just need different time units in that call, e.g. `[[{{#time:Y/m/d|now - 1 month}}]]`.